# get_template_attribute not displaying data in html

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

i came across get_template_attribute in the flask api and thought of it as a great way to achieve partial page rendering.

so the goal was

1. create a 2 layer menu-page layout
2. menu should be static
3. on click of
   menu, page should be shown dynamically without refreshing the entire
   page

so i did something like so

LandingPage.html

```
        <html>
    <head>
    <style>

    html,body{
    height:100%;
    }
    </style>

    <script type="text/javascript">

    function finalConfirmationToStartJob() {
        alert('in here')
        $.ajax({
            type : 'GET',
            url : 'home2',
            data : ''
        });
    };

</script></head>
    <body>
    <table border=1 height=100% width=100%>
    <tr><td colspan='2'/></tr>
    <tr>

    <td width=15%>
    <ul>
    <li>ABC</li>
    <ul>
    <li><a href="javascript:finalConfirmationToStartJob()">ABC1</a></li>
    <li>ABC2</li>
    <li>ABC3</li>
    </ul>
    <li>DEF</li>
    <li>GHI</li>
    <li>JKL</li>
    </ul>
    </td>
    <td>
    {% macro hello(name) %}Hello {{ name }}!{% endmacro %}
    how are you darlings!!! {{hello()}}

    </td>
    </tr>
    <tr><td colspan='2'/></tr>
    </table>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Controller

```
@app.route("/home")
def goto_home():
    return render_template('/LandingPage.html')

@app.route("/home2")
def try_out_macro():
    print 'hellooo elloo'
    hello = get_template_attribute('/LandingPage.html', 'hello')
    return hello('World')
```

However when i do click on the action link, even though the controller actually returns perfect data , the data is not displayed on the screen.

When i hit the url /home2 i do get perfect data, however on click on action link nothing happens on the html

Can someone please help me, i am not sure what i am doing wrong

PS : i got it to work using innr html and div combination, however i would still like to know why the above doesnt work.

Comment: You aren't doing anything with the response in `$.ajax`.

Comment: Hi dirn thank you for responding.
i got it to work using
<code>
function finalConfirmationToStartJob() {
 alert('in here')
 $.ajax({
  type : 'GET',
  url : 'home2',
  data : '',
  success:function(response){
   
   alert(response);
   $('#macro').append(response)
  }
 });
};
</code>
where 'macro' is a div.

my question is wudnt flask display it automatically without having to write the explicitly using inner html.
the API says ---
Loads a macro (or variable) a template exports. This can be used to invoke a macro from within Python code.